# Wrap a tag in div via CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lk863sLx/

Headers is middle in image. Its `a` div and clickable. But I want to click all div. When I put `height:100%` in `a` tag, its crashed centered.

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: what is this? your code doesnt have class name.. its broken..}
display: block !important;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 100%;

}

Comment: Don´t see anything crashing when i add `height:100%`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this `.portfolio-item a.btn-preview {height:100%;}`
[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk863sLx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need like this:

```
.portfolio-item .overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio-item a.btn-preview {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Trade Gothic Normal" !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk863sLx/2/).